# CSS infinite animation is not consistent and laggy after few seconds

Tags: html, css, animation, animate.css

I had a list of thumbnail images spreading across the banner. Each image animates based it own animation-interval and infinite looping the animation.
When I first loaded the page, the animation looks fine and smooth, a few seconds later, the animation pace start to wear off and not consistent. I open up my inspect element, and trace the memory animation, the heap memory increases over time, causes laggy after all.

**HTML**

```
<div class="images">
  <div class="animated fadeIn infinite img1"></div>
  <div class="animated fadeIn infinite img2"></div>
  <div class="animated fadeIn infinite img3"></div>
  <div class="animated fadeIn infinite img4"></div>
  <div class="animated fadeIn infinite img5"></div>
  <div class="animated fadeIn infinite img6"></div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.img1 { animation-duration: 2.65s; }
.img2 { animation-duration: 2.75s; }
.img3 { animation-duration: 2.85s; }
.img4 { animation-duration: 2.95s; }
.img5 { animation-duration: 3.05s; }
.img6 { animation-duration: 3.10s; }
```

**Performance**

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just set `animation-direction` into `alternate` will solve that issue of the performance.

**CSS**

```
animation-direction: alternate;
```

**Performance**

[image]